# Excel VBA update links in workbook to same destination

Tags: vba, excel, merge, sum

**My issue:**

I have a sheet, where I compare two sets of data. These two sets of data, are might have some with the same description number...

In this case I want them to merge, but at the moment I do it manually..

**My data looks like in both ranges:**

```
Date        Description  Amount  
15-12-2017  V576954    -1.289,89  
15-12-2017  V576954    1.289,89  
15-12-2017  V576954    -1.896,45  
19-12-2017  V586894    -789,52  
28-12-2017  GS5155692  -9.286,00  
28-12-2017  GS5155692  9.286,00  
28-12-2017  GS5155692  -11.857,50
```

**GOAL:**

Is there somehow, that I can pull out the Functions a Pivot Table is using, and sum up the values with the same description??
I don't want to get a Pivot Table out of my data, I want to merge the values of the values, which has the same description, along as having the same Date, and the same description :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to sum the values on Column C if the data in Column A and B match, then the following would do that for you:

```
Sub foo()
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets("Sheet1")
ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Summary")
'declare and set your worksheet, change Sheet1 to the sheet you are using
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'find the last row with data on Column A
    For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last
        ws.Cells(i, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-1],C[-2],RC[-2],C[-3],RC[-3])" 'enter sum formula in adjecent cell (Column D)
    Next i
    ws.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Copy 'copy the formula
    ws.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 'paste as values
    Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'delete column C and shift the values from column D to column C
    ws.Range("$A$1:$D$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes 'remove duplicate rows
End Sub
```

Comment: What if the main data sheet is not lined in A, B, C?? And could variate from time to time? I noticed that you want to clear the lines, which I don't wan't to in the sheet where they are aligned in A, B, C... Since they are in a sheet, where they are compared to the other set of data :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to create a new Sheet called Summary and do all the calculations on that sheet so you can still retain your original with all the details. If A, B & C can vary then you would need to use something like Find to find which column refers to Date, Description & Amount and then use them columns to do the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Power Pivot** it is a free add-in that you can get and easily activate. **Get & Transform** by default in Excel 2016.

1. Select any cell in your main table.
2. Go to **Power Pivot** Tab or **Data** in Excel 2016.
3. Select Form **Table/Range** -> **OK**

It will open the **Query Editor** there:

4. Select the columns `[Date]` and `[Description]`
5. Go to **Home** tab and select **Group by**
6. Put a name for the new field.
7. Select the operation.
8. Select the column to Sum.
9. **OK**
10. Go **Home** tab select **Close & Load**
11. Play with your new data!

[image]

You can connect many sources to **Power Query** and it will be a right click **Refresh** and you will have your process done!

Comment: This is great and all, but how do you want me to trigger this from VBA?? :)

Comment: You don't need to. You don't even have to open the query editor. When you want the data it is just right click in the "green" table and click in Refresh.

Comment: The Think is just that I wipe the data, and it variates from time to time... Will this automatically apply itself??

Comment: Yes you can do whatever that you want in the "query editor" there is a lot of tools to transform your data. If you look the gif you will see a box called APPLIED STEPS you can check step by step until the final result. It follows the programming logic line by line. The only thing is be careful when you change a column name, delete or insert a column in the main table. I made this video showing how to use some of the tools in PQ youtu.be/lZA_r5aVetU it is in Spanish but you can follow it. I am using the Excel's English version.